# How can i read the number of bits in matlab using audioread?

Tags: matlab, audio

In older versions of MATLAB, you could use

```
[x,fs,nb]=wavread('audio.wav');
```

But now since wavread is no longer available ( 2019A ), how can i get audioread to return the nb variable? If i try using:

```
[x,fs,nb]=audioread('audio.wav');
```

I'll get an error:
*Error using audioread
Too many output arguments.*

Comment: Audioinfo should give you number of samples and bit depth https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioinfo.html